How is $|z|^2$ not analytic?
I am aware that the C.R equations are not satisfied for $|z|^2$. However, I tried to prove using limits.
My approach was using the formula for derivative of a complex function:
$f'(0) = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}$
$f'(0) = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{x^2+y^2-0}{x+iy}$, putting $y=mx$ in the above equation,
$f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+m^2x^2-0}{x+imx}$
$f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+m^2)x^2}{x(1+im)}$
$f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x(1+m^2)}{(1+im)} = 0$.
As $x$ tends to $0$, the limit also becomes $0$. For different values of $m$ we have the same unique limit around the neighbourhood
of origin. So it should be differentiable around $0$ and therefore analytic. What is wrong here?

Limits agreeing on lines $y=mx$ is not quite enough for the limit to exist, for one thing. But have you checked the Cauchy–Riemann equations for points other than $z=0$? "Differentiable at $0$" is not the same as "differentiable around $0$".

A function holomorphic at a point is holomorphic in a neighborhood. A complex function differentiable at a point as a function of real arguments is not necessarily differentiable in a neighborhood.

Check CR equations.

The OP should cite a published definition of "analytic at a point", since it is not a well-known concept.

Let me summarize the points already made in comments:

The definition of "analytic at $p$" is "differentiable in some neighborhood of $p$". I.e., it is not equivalent to "differentiable at $p$". Showing that the derivative exists at $0$ alone would not be sufficient to prove it is analytic at $0$. And certainly, showing it differentiable at $0$ by itself proves nothing about differentiability at any nearby points.
To show that a double limit at $0$ converges, it is not enough to show that it converges along all lines of the form $y = mx$. A well-known example is $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0+, 0)} x^y$. If you examine only lines $y = mx$, you will find the limit is always $1$. But along the line $x = 0$ (which cannot be expressed as $y = mx$), the limit is $0$. And further, if you are allowed to approach on curves that are not lines, the limit can be other values. If you want to find out how a function of two or more variables behaves near a point, looking along lines is not sufficient.

The truth is, $f(z) = |z|^2 = z\bar z$ is complex-differentiable at $z = 0$. The limit here will converge, even though your argument is too weak to show it. But to be analytic at $0$, the derivative must also converge at other points around $0$, and that does not happen. For any point $p$, we have
$$\begin{align}f'(p) &= \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(p+z) - f(p)}z\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(p+z)(\bar p+\bar z) - p\bar p}z\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}\bar z + \bar p + p \frac{\bar z}z
\end{align}$$
and for $p \ne 0$, while the first two terms obviously converge, the third does not. For expressing $z = re^{i\theta}$, we find that $z\to 0$ is equivalent to $r \to 0$, without any condition being placed on $\theta$, and $\frac{\bar z}z = e^{-i2\theta}$ will approach different values depending on $\theta$ as $r \to 0$.
So with $f$ being differentiable only at $0$, it is not analytic anywhere - not even at $0$.
